# Exclude empty variables from serialised array print out

Tags: php, serialization

I have a serialised array stored in the database.

I have the following code printing out the data.

```
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
$data[$key]=preg_replace("/(\015\012)|(\015)|(\012)/","<br /><br 
/>",$data[$key]); 
if ($key=='Submit' || $key=='loggedin' || $key=='submit' || 
$key=='ConfirmEmail') continue;
```

Is it possible that I could exclude empty variables from the print out e.g. like this one 
    "GroupMemberName5";s:0:"";

Comment: Not sure why my question and proposed answer has been marked down @visual-vincent @jay-shankar-gupta? Cannot see any comments. Help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
if ($data[$key]=='') continue;
```